# Angular 14: Open SVG paths automatically join when dynamically rendered from data object

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I created an app to parse SVG code into a JSON object which can be saved to a database and another app to dynamically render it on a webpage.  When it renders it comes out looking like this
[image: screenshot of demo]

As you can see the open paths seem to connect and partially fill the svg, however when running the raw SVG file it doesn't have that problem which you can see by running the snippet below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 25.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="part_x5F_assembly" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
     y="0px" viewBox="0 0 513 225" style="enable-background:new 0 0 513 225;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<path id="rivet_x5F_d" class="st0" d="M280.56015,179.823257l-1.200012,3.900024l-0.192719,8.851166
    c0.333344,0.799988,2.016693,0.899994,2.200012,0.100006l0.192719-8.851196L280.56015,179.823257z M281.015656,204.766052
    c3.433411,0.268616,6.039734,1.376923,6.010345,2.640396c-0.032501,1.397034-3.274994,2.454742-7.24234,2.362457
    c-3.967316-0.09227-7.157135-1.299591-7.124634-2.696625c0.02951-1.269516,2.777527-2.267685,6.243713-2.368454
     M281.562378,183.824097c-0.009552,0.214111-0.510468,0.365646-1.118805,0.338486
    c-0.608368-0.027161-1.093781-0.222763-1.084229-0.436874 M281.16745,200.380295l-0.207306,6.842987l0.000427,0.000168
    c-0.099365,0.404099-1.80249,0.544724-2.09314,0.05098l0.100006-6.952957 M287.029053,207.274704l-0.104156,6.354156
    c-0.032715,1.406219-3.275391,2.47139-7.242706,2.379105c-3.94046-0.091644-7.113708-1.290634-7.124481-2.684692l0.102417-6.400009"
    />
<path id="washer_x5F_d" class="st0" d="M288.090179,171.017059c-0.041382,1.396545-3.308899,2.432846-7.298218,2.314651
    c-3.989319-0.11821-7.189758-1.346161-7.148376-2.742706s3.308899-2.432846,7.298218-2.314636
    S288.131561,169.620529,288.090179,171.017059z M273.643646,170.518005l-0.078186,1.034546
    c-0.041382,1.396545,3.159058,2.624481,7.148376,2.742691s7.256836-0.918091,7.298218-2.314636l0.077667-0.94104
     M280.856323,170.420334c-0.589935-0.017471-1.072998,0.131073-1.078949,0.331802
    c-0.005951,0.200745,0.467468,0.37764,1.057434,0.395111c0.589935,0.017487,1.072998-0.131073,1.078949-0.331802
    S281.446289,170.43782,280.856323,170.420334z"/>
<path id="rivet_x5F_c" class="st0" d="M202.055603,107.303535l-1.200012,3.900024l-0.099991,6.099976
    c0.333344,0.799988,1.916687,0.799988,2.099991,0l0.200012-6L202.055603,107.303535z M202.514557,132.098129
    c3.433395,0.269867,6.039536,1.385056,6.009949,2.65686c-0.032715,1.406219-3.275375,2.471375-7.242706,2.379089
    c-3.967331-0.09227-7.156967-1.307053-7.124268-2.713272c0.029724-1.277863,2.71019-2.274094,6.176392-2.376053
     M203.057846,111.304375c-0.009567,0.214111-0.510483,0.365654-1.118835,0.338486
    c-0.608353-0.027161-1.093765-0.222755-1.084198-0.436867 M202.655579,125.70356l-0.199982,8.999992l0.000443,0.000183
    c-0.170944,0.441269-2.141541,0.370682-2.201691-0.102081l0.301254-9.398094 M208.524506,134.75499l-0.104172,6.354156
    c-0.0327,1.406219-3.275375,2.47139-7.242706,2.379105c-3.94043-0.09166-7.113693-1.290634-7.124481-2.684708l0.102448-6.400009"/>
<path id="washer_x5F_c" class="st0" d="M209.470398,99.449356c-0.041382,1.396545-3.308914,2.432846-7.298218,2.314636
    c-3.989319-0.118202-7.189758-1.346146-7.148376-2.742691s3.308899-2.432846,7.298218-2.314636
    C206.31134,96.824867,209.51178,98.052811,209.470398,99.449356z M195.023865,98.950294l-0.078186,1.034546
    c-0.041382,1.396545,3.159058,2.624489,7.148376,2.742699c3.989304,0.118202,7.256836-0.918098,7.298218-2.314636l0.077667-0.94104
     M202.236542,98.852631c-0.589951-0.017487-1.073013,0.131073-1.078964,0.331802s0.467484,0.377632,1.057434,0.395111
    s1.073013-0.131073,1.078964-0.33181C203.299927,99.047005,202.826492,98.87011,202.236542,98.852631z"/>
<path id="rivet_x5F_b" class="st0" d="M89.075882,140.508438l-1.200012,3.900024l-0.224045,8.750336
    c0.333351,0.799988,2.03228,0.815643,2.215591,0.015656l0.208466-8.666016L89.075882,140.508438z M89.534836,165.30304
    c3.433395,0.269852,6.039536,1.385056,6.009949,2.656845c-0.032707,1.406219-3.275375,2.47139-7.242706,2.379105
    s-7.156967-1.307053-7.12426-2.713272c0.029724-1.277878,2.71019-2.274109,6.176392-2.376068 M90.078125,144.509277
    c-0.009567,0.214111-0.510483,0.365662-1.118828,0.338486c-0.608353-0.027161-1.093765-0.222748-1.084206-0.436859
     M89.66156,161.556778l-0.185684,6.351685l0.000435,0.000168c-0.196495,0.547379-2.125908,0.484634-2.201683-0.102066
    l0.195755-6.688034 M95.544785,167.959885l-0.104164,6.354172c-0.032707,1.406219-3.275375,2.471375-7.242706,2.379105
    c-3.940437-0.09166-7.113693-1.290634-7.124481-2.684708l0.10244-6.400009"/>
<path id="washer_x5F_b" class="st0" d="M96.553238,132.554749c-0.041382,1.396545-3.308907,2.432846-7.298225,2.314636
    c-3.989311-0.11821-7.189751-1.346146-7.148369-2.742691s3.308907-2.432846,7.298225-2.314636
    C93.39418,129.930252,96.59462,131.158203,96.553238,132.554749z M82.106705,132.055679l-0.078186,1.034561
    c-0.041382,1.39653,3.159058,2.624481,7.148369,2.742691c3.989319,0.118195,7.256844-0.918091,7.298225-2.314636l0.077667-0.94104
     M89.319389,131.958023c-0.589951-0.017487-1.073021,0.131073-1.078972,0.331802s0.467484,0.377625,1.057434,0.395111
    c0.589951,0.017471,1.073021-0.131073,1.078964-0.331802C90.382767,132.15239,89.90934,131.975494,89.319389,131.958023z"/>
<path id="rivet_x5F_a" class="st0" d="M10.56743,67.874428l-1.200012,3.900024l-0.099991,6.099976
    c0.333348,0.799988,1.916682,0.799988,2.099991,0l0.200012-6L10.56743,67.874428z M11.026379,92.669029
    c3.433398,0.269859,6.039536,1.385056,6.009954,2.656853c-0.032709,1.406219-3.27538,2.471375-7.242709,2.379097
    s-7.156969-1.307053-7.12426-2.713272c0.029723-1.27787,2.710191-2.274101,6.176391-2.37606 M11.569667,71.875267
    c-0.009562,0.214111-0.510477,0.365662-1.118827,0.338493c-0.608349-0.027168-1.093762-0.222763-1.084201-0.436874
     M11.167405,86.274452l-0.199982,9l0.000436,0.000175c-0.200418,0.56646-2.096251,0.608124-2.201689-0.102074l0.301259-9.398102
     M17.036333,95.325882l-0.104168,6.354164c-0.032707,1.406219-3.275379,2.471382-7.242707,2.379097
    c-3.940436-0.091652-7.11369-1.290634-7.124483-2.6847l0.102445-6.400009"/>
<path id="washer_x5F_a" class="st0" d="M18.06496,58.3578c-0.04138,1.396542-3.308907,2.432842-7.298223,2.314636
    s-7.189753-1.346149-7.148373-2.742695s3.308906-2.432842,7.298223-2.314636
    C14.905905,55.733307,18.10634,56.961254,18.06496,58.3578z M3.618422,57.858734l-0.078183,1.03455
    c-0.04138,1.396542,3.159055,2.624489,7.148373,2.742695c3.989317,0.118202,7.256844-0.918095,7.298223-2.31464l0.077665-0.941036
     M10.831109,57.76107c-0.589952-0.017483-1.073023,0.131073-1.078971,0.331806
    c-0.005948,0.200729,0.467481,0.377628,1.057432,0.395107c0.589951,0.017479,1.073022-0.131073,1.07897-0.331806
    S11.42106,57.778549,10.831109,57.76107z"/>
<path id="middle_x5F_arm" class="st0" d="M273.167419,193.074448l-0.099976,5.299988 M282.967407,195.074448l-0.099976,5.199982
     M398.667419,216.974442l-0.200012,5.299988l-33-5.399994l-82.599976-16.600006
    c-4.169067,0.391602-8.058319-0.18335-9.799988-1.899994l-62.100021-12.5 M365.567444,211.574448l-0.100037,5.299988
     M187.867416,175.974442l-102.5-20.600006c-7.529388-1.958847-2.670563-4.74707,2.364716-4.700012 M205.167435,179.374435
    l67.999985,13.700012c2.037537,1.849976,5.377686,2.394348,9.799988,2l82.600037,16.5l33.099976,5.399994l-29.700012-7.600006
    l-81.599976-17.199982c-1.021851-1.187531-3.303101-1.890656-6-2.100006 M89.924301,150.670502
    c0.635376,0.035706,1.407196,0.136642,2.243103,0.30394l89.100006,18.800018 M279.218445,190.074417
    c-0.380493-0.043671-0.936951,0.011932-1.551025,0.100037l-78.699997-16.600006 M195.167435,182.674454l-109.900024-22
    c-2.296021-0.453644-3.921844-1.453156-3.899994-2.399994l0.100006-5.300018"/>
<path id="outer_x5F_arm_x5F_b" class="st0" d="M45.567429,93.274452l0.099976-5.200012 M188.76741,119.874428l0.200012-5.199982
     M364.367432,158.174454l0.099976-5.200012 M387.467407,159.374435l0.200012-5.299988 M397.967407,164.674454l0.100037-5.300018
     M478.567444,180.974442l0.099976-5.299988 M511.667419,181.074448l-0.099976,5.299988l-33-5.399994l-80.600037-16.299988
    l-10.5-5.300018l-23.099976-1.199982l-166.000015-33.400002c-3.749298-0.925629-7.224976-2.850037-9.600006-4.900024
    c-19.999969-1.637512-39.062469-4.543762-54.899994-8.899994 M200.867416,112.874428l-5.100006-2.599976
    c-33.416641-0.266701-72.937469-10.350037-81.299988-18.200012h-0.399994 M92.26741,90.874428
    c-25.791634-3.075012-63.291634-10.84584-62.299988-14.699982c-7.478088-0.823578-14.246858-1.218781-18.5-1.100006
     M9.367417,75.274452c-1.606455,0.0392-4.012516,0.425331-5.318726,1.196838
    c-1.608228,0.949898-1.606133,2.408119,2.918732,3.603149l38.699982,8c17.808372,1.704147,38.058372,5.162476,52.400024,7.899994
     M288.967407,132.674454l80.5,17l23.600037,1.199982l14.299988,7.300018l74.700012,15.299988l29.599976,7.600006l-33-5.399994
    l-80.599976-16.300018l-10.400024-5.299988l-23.200012-1.100006l-165.999985-33.500008
    c-3.642517-0.969666-6.851532-2.51358-9.5-4.799988c-21.741653-1.791695-45.866653-5.416695-63.200012-11.399994
     M274.067444,129.574448l-68.900009-14.500008l-2.200012-1.100006 M105.567429,102.774452
    c-15.331238-3.193787-38.674988-7.350037-60-9.5L6.867417,85.374428c-2.095016-0.498901-3.899976-1.19413-3.899994-2.399994
    l0.100006-5.299988"/>
<path id="outer_x5F_arm_x5F_a" class="st0" d="M3.767426,16.274456c10.125015-0.318788,27.093765,14.274963,31.599991,25.400024
     M3.967423,10.974467l-0.199997,5.299989 M34.467422,42.774456l-0.100006,5.299988
    c19.900024,4.183308,36.775024,16.412472,37.600006,25.200008 M71.867416,73.874428L71.76741,79.07444l12,4.100006
    l69.200012,62.299995 M83.967422,77.874428l-0.200012,5.300018 M163.467422,139.174454l-0.100006,5.299988l-0.299988,3
     M170.867416,154.874435l-0.100006,5.200012 M217.76741,194.674454l-0.199982,5.199982l-16.200012-11.5l-30.600006-28.299988
    l-18.099976-6.100006l0.099976-5.299988 M201.467422,183.174454l-0.100006,5.199982 M97.467422,76.374428l66,62.800026
    l-0.700012,8.199982l13.300018,4.5l32.199982,30.5l9.5,12.300018l-16.299988-11.5l-30.600006-28.300018l-18.100006-6.199982
    l0.600006-8.300018L83.967422,77.874428l-12.100006-4c4.462524-11.387508-16.662476-27.387508-37.399994-31.099972
    c7.706268-7.162537-17.94998-32.225037-30.5-31.799988C2.892442,8.007751,2.940156,5.352093,4.934109,3.757752
    c3.323246-2.65723,11.916666-1.979167,14.033316,0.016703l15.899992,14.700013
    c17.025024,36.137451,42.525024,25.637451,50.5,53.799984C87.189316,72.596291,94.908066,74.299416,97.467422,76.374428
     M3.767426,16.274456L3.06743,12.574443l0.205895-5.500024 M12.19432,4.168589
    c-0.489383-0.015873-0.891171,0.127439-0.89742,0.320095c-0.006248,0.192657,0.385408,0.361704,0.874791,0.377577
    c0.489383,0.015873,0.891171-0.127439,0.89742-0.320096C13.075359,4.353508,12.683702,4.184462,12.19432,4.168589z
     M90.697182,76.792923c-0.489388-0.015877-0.891174,0.127441-0.897423,0.320099
    c-0.006248,0.19265,0.385406,0.361702,0.874794,0.377571c0.48938,0.015877,0.891167-0.127434,0.897415-0.320091
    S91.186562,76.808792,90.697182,76.792923z"/>
<path id="support_x5F_arm" class="st0" d="M284.467407,124.374428l-74.199997-71
    c-4.281219-3.262512-16.437469-1.762512-13.599976,1.5l78.799973,70.5c-3.324951,2.331238,4.849976,4.837532,10.200012,3.600014
    C291.017456,127.736916,290.173706,125.486916,284.467407,124.374428z M274.567444,129.974442L196.567429,60.17448
    c-0.231354-0.241238-0.432098-0.41967-0.432098-0.691406l0.002686,0.011932l0.100006-5.512695 M289.267456,126.874428
    l-0.200012,5.300026c-1.029175,3.124969-13.299988,3.374969-14.5-0.399994l0.099976-5.20002 M203.447128,53.752544
    c-0.522079,0-0.945312,0.150402-0.945312,0.335938c0,0.185532,0.423233,0.335938,0.945312,0.335938
    s0.945312-0.150406,0.945312-0.335938C204.392441,53.902946,203.969208,53.752544,203.447128,53.752544z M281.967438,126.388496
    c-0.522095,0-0.945312,0.150406-0.945312,0.335938c0,0.185539,0.423218,0.335938,0.945312,0.335938
    c0.522064,0,0.945312-0.150398,0.945312-0.335938C282.91275,126.538902,282.489502,126.388496,281.967438,126.388496z"/>
</svg>
```

I created 2 components for rendering the SVG which are called `SvgBuilder` and `SvgComponent`.  The Template files for these components look like this

***svg-builder.component.svg***

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" [attr.viewBox]="GraphicViewBox" width="100%" height="100%%">

<!--  The css classes are inserted here -->
<style type="text/css" *ngIf="GlobalStyling !== ''" [innerHtml]="insertStyles()"></style>

  <!--  The svg data is iterated here as a symbol  -->
  <defs>
      <symbol #symbolShell [attr.id]="SvgData.graphicId" [attr.viewBox]="GraphicViewBox">

          <!--  The svg component  -->
          <svg:g svg-component *ngFor="let item of SvgData.elements" [ElementData]="item"></svg:g>

      </symbol>
  </defs>
  
  <!--  Graphic used here  -->
  <svg>
      <use [attr.xlink:href]="SymbolLink" />
  </svg>

</svg>
```

***svg.component.svg***

```
<svg>

  <g *ngIf="TemplateType === 'single element'" [innerHtml]="insertElement()"></g>

  <g #graphicContainer *ngIf="TemplateType == 'group element'">

      <svg:g svg-component *ngFor="let item of ElementData.subElements" [ElementData]="item"></svg:g>

  </g>

  <linearGradient #graphicContainer *ngIf="TemplateType === 'linear gradient'">

      <svg:g svg-component *ngFor="let item of ElementData.subElements" [ElementData]="item"></svg:g>

  </linearGradient>

  <radialGradient #graphicContainer *ngIf="TemplateType === 'radial gradient'">

      <svg:g svg-component *ngFor="let item of ElementData.subElements" [ElementData]="item"></svg:g>

  </radialGradient>

  <symbol #graphicContainer *ngIf="TemplateType === 'linear gradient'">

      <svg:g svg-component *ngFor="let item of ElementData.subElements" [ElementData]="item"></svg:g>

  </symbol>

</svg>
```

Does this shed any light on what could be happening in Angular to make that occur?  You can test it for yourself [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f5cfwj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmicro-frontends%2Fsvg-builder%2Fdemo.svg) by following the instructions on the screen copying and pasting the code in the `demo.svg` file which is located at

> src/app/micro-frontends/svg-builder

incase it for some reason isn't the file already open when the stackblitz loads.

Comment: if I change the stroke-width from 0.022 to 2 I can see the drawing but I can't see the paths that _look partially filled_  Can you edit your question and point out the path/paths that look partially filled?

Comment: on my end all of them look partially filled.

Comment: however I am using angular and rendering it dynamically, maybe that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my problem wasn't the SVG, it was the function I created to build the css properties which looks like this

```
private createCssProperty(prop: OvaadSvgStyleProperty): string{
    return `${prop.property}:${prop.setting}`;
  }
```

The problem is I forgot to add a `;` at the end of the string making it to where the css rules were being structured like this

```
.st0{ fill:none stroke: #000000 stroke-width: 0.6 stroke-linecap: round stroke-linejoin: round stroke-miterlimit: 10 }
```

which wasn't making sense to the browser so I added the semicolon at the end of the string as follows

```
private createCssProperty(prop: OvaadSvgStyleProperty): string{
    return `${prop.property}:${prop.setting};`;
  }
```

and it works perfectly now :).